# How to use an already built Caffe when running py-faster-rcnn?

Tags: python-2.7, path, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to build and run [py-faster-rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) model on my Ubuntu 16.04.

However, when I run `./tools/demo.py` (as stated in the [installation guide](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn#demo)), I get the following error:

```
➜  py-faster-rcnn git:(master) ✗ ./tools/demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/demo.py", line 18, in <module>
    from fast_rcnn.test import im_detect
  File "/home/denis/WEB/DeepLearning/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    import caffe
  File "/home/denis/WEB/DeepLearning/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
  File "/home/denis/WEB/DeepLearning/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: No module named _caffe
```

---

Before attempting to install py-faster-rcnn, I've installed `Caffe` in my `~/code/caffe` folder and it seems to work fine:

```
➜  ~ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import caffe
>>> print caffe.__version__
1.0.0-rc3
```

So, if I can import `caffe` module in python environment, I assume I've installed it successfully.

Here're the commands I've used (from the official guide):

```
sudo make all
sudo make test
sudo make runtest
sudo make pycaffe
sudo make distribute
```

Then I've cloned the [py-faster-rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) repository in my `~/WEB/DeepLearning` folder.

After that I've followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn#installation-sufficient-for-the-demo) from the repo:

1. Clone the repo
2. `cd $FRCN_ROOT/lib && make`
3. `cd $FRCN_ROOT/caffe-fast-rcnn`
4. `make -j8 && make pycaffe`   (I didn't run this)
5. `cd $FRCN_ROOT && ./data/scripts/fetch_faster_rcnn_models.sh`
6. `cd $FRCN_ROOT && ./tools/demo.py`

So, step 4 in the installation guide says I have to build `caffe` and `pycaffe` in `$FRCN_ROOT/caffe-fast-rcnn` folder. The contents of `caffe-fast-rcnn` folder seem to be identical with the original `caffe` repository from which I've built `Caffe`.

So, it seems that I don't need to build `caffe` again, right? When trying to run the demo, I've skipped the step of building `caffe` and got the error stated above.

After googling for a while, I've found out that my issue is connected with path environment variables, so below are my path variables in `.bashrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:~/code/caffe/distribute/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python2.7

export PYTHONPATH=~/code/caffe/python:$PYTHONPATH
```

---

Am I doing something wrong and I have to change my path variables somehow?
Or I really need to build `caffe` again, but in a `caffe-fast-rcnn` folder?

And what about this `distribute` folder I've generated in `~/code/caffe/distribute` by running `sudo make distribute`? Is it of any use? If so, how should I use it? The official documentation is not very clear about it.

---

A simple, clear and detailed explanation on how to use an already built Caffe framework with other projects like Faster-RCNN would be really helpful.

Comment: I am on the same boat! Great question and level of description. I wonder what people usually do when working with other projects once Caffe is already built. I am also assuming they wouldn't have to rebuild everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this for a while and then got it working as below.

First, check `PYTHONPATH` env variable. It should have python path like, for eg. based on your python version and installation

```
PYTHONPATH = /usr/lib/python2.7
```

If its empty, you can set it with python path captured in your python shell. To check python path information, open python shell and type below

```
>>import sys
>>for p in sys.path
...  print(p)
```

It will list you all python path info, for eg

```
...
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
...
```

If you have installed caffe already and want it to configure to be used by python, you just need to update your `PYTHONPATH` env variable by adding path to your **/caffe-installation-path/python** folder to it, like

```
export PYTHONPATH = /home/mypc/caffe-master/python:$PYTHONPATH
```

**Note:-** You don't need to rebuild caffe but configure caffe and python in PYTHONPATH env variable correctly.